# Does other frontend framework have similar issue like AngularJS?

Tags: xss, rce

I'm reading [an article](https://speakerdeck.com/masatokinugawa/how-i-hacked-microsoft-teams-and-got-150000-dollars-in-pwn2own?slide=33) that talks about XSS exploitation on AngularJS,

[image]

AngularJS will render the template in [ng-html](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml), and it bypasses sanitize-html.

My questions,

1. I'm wondering if other frameworks like Vue.js and React is also vulnerable to this attack?

   - I tried to use `{{ }}` in React and it's not executed by `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` method.
   - I tried to use `{{ }}` in Vue.js and it's not parsed by v-html directive.
2. Why isn't other frameworks affected in this way?